# How to get wifi points list?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to get SSID all wifi points, witch available for the android device at the moment. Can app do this without location permission?

Comment: Do you tried without `location permission`? and checked here https://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: Sure, I try load wifi points with permission, android return empty list.

Comment: why do you want to get without permission ?

Comment: Because my app needs only wifi point list. And I think about device battery.

Comment: How it is related `location permission` . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html

Comment: The SSID may be <unknown ssid> if there is no network currently connected, or if the caller has insufficient permissions to access the SSID.

Comment: Please check my code, if you can help https://github.com/SimpleSmartExtensions/SmartExtensionAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/schoolhelper/simplerelecontrol/datalayer/LoadWifiList.kt